# setInterval with time parameter based on observable variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I cant make **setInterval** worked properly, with Time parameter value based on my API (Observable method)

my service :

```
getInterval(): Observable<string>{
    return this.http.get('http://my.api/dashboard/api/sysparam/refreshinterval')
    .map((res:Response) => <string> res.json().refreshInterval)   
}
```

Here is my observable to get interval value :

```
this.ConnectionService.getInterval().subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.interval_2 = data;
                }
            )
```

and if i put this way :

```
this.intervalStatisticalIndicator = setInterval(() => {
                this.getDataStatisticalIndicator();
            },this.interval_2);
```

the page is just keep refreshing , as its ignored the value inside the **interval_2**

but if i assign any number manually into the variable ( without observable ) , it worked fine .

Is there something i did wrong ? should i use other method instead observable ?
i'm quite new to angular & javascript thing so please any help would by appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with observables only. You do not need `setInterval`.

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { interval } from 'rxjs/observable/interval';

this.ConnectionService.getInterval()
  .pipe(switchMap(data => interval(data))
  .subscribe(() =>  this.getDataStatisticalIndicator())
```

Comment: Thanks for the input . but i get this error  :  Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'